# $_GET variables being passed with empty string values

Tags: php, get

I have my local test server and my running server. On the test server, I use this url:

```
http://localhost/?&start[]=0&duration_[]=2&name[]=David&setting[]=26&start[]=6&duration[]=18&name[]=john&setting[]=26
```

From this URL, I use a for loop to run through the array:

```
$num = count($_GET['start']);
if (isset($_GET['start']) && count($_GET['start']))
{
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
        echo "Time: " . intval(trim($_GET['start'][$i]));
    }
}
```

This works like a charm. However, when I run it on my actual server, I get all the variables returning as empty strings... Here is the var_dump:

```
 ["start"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["duration"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["setting"]=>
  string(0) ""
```

Anyone have any idea what's happening here? I've put the same for-loop test code from above and I'm obviously not getting anything besides: "Time: "

Comment: Off-topic comment: why not use `foreach`?

Comment: I'm getting multiple variables within the for loop which is more intuitive, I think. I've simplified the code to loop through one array ($_GET['start']) for this question rather than all of them simply to show the problem.

Comment: you should use http_build_query() for building the url or the string encoding will be of

Comment: "This works like a charm. However, when I run it on my actual server, " — This indicates that the problem isn't do with with the code you've provided. Maybe you have some URL rewriting configuration on the live server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the code or the $_GET method or the difference of servers (well a slight difference). I didn't realize that when I was using filter_var() on my main server, my arrays were being turned into strings. This bit of the sanitization code that caused the problem was not on my test server. As per the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

> Value to filter. Note that scalar values are converted to string internally before they are filtered.

This is the first time I've made a function using the array capabilties of the $_GET variable so I didn't realize that when sanitizing, I was sanitizing each GET variable where in this new instance, I was sanitizing each GET array, rather than GET value.

The code I was using was:

```
$get_arr = $var_arr['_GET'];
$get_key = array_keys($get_arr);
$_GET[$get_key[$g_a]] = trim(filter_var($_GET[$get_key[$g_a]], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
```

The code that I changed it to

```
$get_arr = $var_arr['_GET'];
$get_key = array_keys($get_arr);
$_GET[$get_key[$k]][$i] = trim(filter_var($_GET[$get_key[$k]][$i], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
```

It's only a slight distinction, but enough of one to have me debugging this for a couple of days. Hopefully this helps someone else along the way.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the [] after your vars.

```
http://localhost/?start=0
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/?start[]=0
```

your passing [] as your string so it spitting that out, remove the [].

Comment: its an array, he wants an array

Comment: where did he say he wants an array?, what his code says and what he wants might be different

Comment: yeah i get that, he has not said he wants an array is my point. his code says that, but if he knew what his code did he wouldn't  be here

Comment: The URL uses array syntax. The code expects array syntax. The OP says it works in his test environment. I can't see anything at all in the question which indicates that "Don't use arrays" could solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for your input, it has been filed appropriately

Comment: I appreciate your answer @ATechGuy, but I was more concerned about why my $_GET variables were being turned into strings when I expected them to return actual values. Sorry if I didn't make that too clear in my question. You can see the answer I've posted if you're curious as to why my spaghetti wasn't working.

Comment: Anytime @DJSweetness. Glad you got it sorted out. :)